# Haskell Stack: Missing C library Xft when using stack building X11-xft?

Tags: haskell, x11, haskell-stack, xmonad

```
⚓  ~  stack build X11-xft
X11-xft-0.3.1: configure

--  While building package X11-xft-0.3.1 using:
      /home/suzumiya/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.0.0_ghc-8.0.1 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/Cabal-1.24.0.0 configure --with-ghc=/home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/suzumiya/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/pkgdb --package-db=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/pkgdb --libdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/lib --bindir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/bin --datadir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/share --libexecdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/etc --docdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/doc/X11-xft-0.3.1 --htmldir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/doc/X11-xft-0.3.1 --haddockdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/doc/X11-xft-0.3.1 --dependency=X11=X11-1.6.1.2-22TNurK7nbm9YWNib5sChe --dependency=base=base-4.9.0.0 --dependency=utf8-string=utf8-string-1.0.1.1-2T8mBCuEDlXDo8zed8Onw4
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/X11-xft-0.3.1.log

    Configuring X11-xft-0.3.1...
    Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.0.0_ghc-8.0.1: Missing dependency on a foreign
    library:
    * Missing C library: Xft
    This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
    provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
    already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
    --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
 ⚓  ~  ls /usr/include/X11/Xft/Xft.h 
/usr/include/X11/Xft/Xft.h
 ⚓  ~  ls /usr/lib/libXft.so 
/usr/lib/libXft.so@
```

I have installed the xft and can find it on default path. But it still says that there is a C library missing.
using arch x86_64, stack 1.3.2, sandboxed ghc

```
 ⚓  ~  pkg-config --version
0.29.1
 ⚓  ~  pkg-config xft --libs
-lXft
```

and detailed debug info listed:

```
 ⚓  ~  stack build X11-xft --verbose
Version 1.3.2 x86_64
Compiled with:
- Cabal-1.24.0.0
- Glob-0.7.14
- HUnit-1.5.0.0
- MonadRandom-0.4.2.3
- QuickCheck-2.9.2
- SHA-1.6.4.2
- StateVar-1.1.0.4
- aeson-1.0.2.1
- aeson-compat-0.3.6
- annotated-wl-pprint-0.7.0
- ansi-terminal-0.6.2.3
- ansi-wl-pprint-0.6.7.3
- array-0.5.1.1
- asn1-encoding-0.9.4
- asn1-parse-0.9.4
- asn1-types-0.3.2
- async-2.1.1
- attoparsec-0.13.1.0
- auto-update-0.1.4
- base-4.9.0.0
- base-compat-0.9.1
- base-orphans-0.5.4
- base16-bytestring-0.1.1.6
- base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1
- bifunctors-5.4.1
- binary-0.8.3.0
- binary-tagged-0.1.4.2
- bitarray-0.0.1.1
- blaze-builder-0.4.0.2
- blaze-html-0.8.1.3
- blaze-markup-0.7.1.1
- byteable-0.1.1
- bytestring-0.10.8.1
- call-stack-0.1.0
- case-insensitive-1.2.0.7
- cereal-0.5.4.0
- clock-0.7.2
- comonad-5
- conduit-1.2.8
- conduit-extra-1.1.15
- connection-0.2.6
- constraints-0.8
- containers-0.5.7.1
- contravariant-1.4
- cookie-0.4.2.1
- cryptohash-0.11.9
- cryptohash-conduit-0.1.1
- cryptonite-0.21
- data-default-class-0.1.2.0
- deepseq-1.4.2.0
- digest-0.0.1.2
- directory-1.2.6.2
- distributive-0.5.1
- dlist-0.8.0.2
- easy-file-0.2.1
- either-4.4.1.1
- enclosed-exceptions-1.0.2
- errors-2.1.3
- exceptions-0.8.3
- extra-1.5.1
- fast-logger-2.4.7
- file-embed-0.0.10
- filelock-0.1.0.1
- filepath-1.4.1.0
- foundation-0.0.3
- free-4.12.4
- fsnotify-0.2.1
- generic-deriving-1.11.1
- generics-sop-0.2.3.0
- ghc-boot-th-8.0.1
- ghc-prim-0.5.0.0
- gitrev-1.2.0
- hashable-1.2.5.0
- hastache-0.6.1
- hinotify-0.3.9
- hit-0.6.3
- hourglass-0.2.10
- hpack-0.16.0
- hpc-0.6.0.3
- hspec-2.3.2
- hspec-core-2.3.2
- hspec-discover-2.3.2
- hspec-expectations-0.8.2
- hspec-smallcheck-0.4.1
- http-api-data-0.3.5
- http-client-0.5.5
- http-client-tls-0.3.3.1
- http-conduit-2.2.3
- http-types-0.9.1
- ieee754-0.7.9
- integer-gmp-1.0.0.1
- lifted-async-0.9.1
- lifted-base-0.2.3.8
- logict-0.6.0.2
- memory-0.14
- microlens-0.4.7.0
- mime-types-0.1.0.7
- mmorph-1.0.9
- monad-control-1.0.1.0
- monad-logger-0.3.20.1
- monad-loops-0.4.3
- monad-unlift-0.2.0
- mono-traversable-1.0.1.1
- mtl-2.2.1
- network-2.6.3.1
- network-uri-2.6.1.0
- old-locale-1.0.0.7
- old-time-1.1.0.3
- open-browser-0.2.1.0
- optparse-applicative-0.13.0.0
- optparse-simple-0.0.3
- parsec-3.1.11
- path-0.5.11
- path-io-1.2.2
- path-pieces-0.2.1
- patience-0.1.1
- pem-0.2.2
- persistent-2.6
- persistent-sqlite-2.6
- persistent-template-2.5.1.6
- pid1-0.1.0.1
- prelude-extras-0.4.0.3
- pretty-1.1.3.3
- primitive-0.6.1.0
- process-1.4.2.0
- profunctors-5.2
- project-template-0.2.0
- quickcheck-io-0.1.4
- random-1.1
- regex-applicative-0.3.3
- regex-applicative-text-0.1.0.1
- resource-pool-0.2.3.2
- resourcet-1.1.9
- retry-0.7.4.2
- rts-1.0
- safe-0.3.11
- safe-exceptions-0.1.4.0
- scientific-0.3.4.9
- semigroupoids-5.1
- semigroups-0.18.2
- setenv-0.1.1.3
- silently-1.2.5
- smallcheck-1.1.1
- socks-0.5.5
- split-0.2.3.1
- stm-2.4.4.1
- stm-chans-3.0.0.4
- store-0.3
- store-core-0.3
- streaming-commons-0.1.17
- syb-0.6
- system-fileio-0.3.16.3
- system-filepath-0.4.13.4
- tagged-0.8.5
- tar-0.5.0.3
- template-haskell-2.11.0.0
- temporary-1.2.0.4
- text-1.2.2.1
- text-binary-0.2.1.1
- text-metrics-0.2.0
- tf-random-0.5
- th-expand-syns-0.4.2.0
- th-lift-0.7.6
- th-lift-instances-0.1.11
- th-orphans-0.13.3
- th-reify-many-0.1.6
- th-utilities-0.2.0.1
- time-1.6.0.1
- time-locale-compat-0.1.1.3
- tls-1.3.9
- transformers-0.5.2.0
- transformers-base-0.4.4
- transformers-compat-0.5.1.4
- unexceptionalio-0.3.0
- unicode-transforms-0.2.1
- unix-2.7.2.0
- unix-compat-0.4.3.1
- unix-time-0.3.7
- unordered-containers-0.2.7.2
- uri-bytestring-0.2.2.1
- utf8-string-1.0.1.1
- uuid-types-1.0.3
- vector-0.11.0.0
- vector-algorithms-0.7.0.1
- vector-binary-instances-0.2.3.4
- void-0.7.1
- x509-1.6.5
- x509-store-1.6.2
- x509-system-1.6.4
- x509-validation-1.6.5
- yaml-0.8.21.1
- zip-archive-0.3.0.5
- zlib-0.6.1.2
- zlib-bindings-0.1.1.5

2017-01-30 19:43:15.759454: [debug] Checking for project config at: /home/suzumiya/stack.yaml
@(Stack/Config.hs:863:9)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.759977: [debug] Checking for project config at: /home/stack.yaml
@(Stack/Config.hs:863:9)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.760139: [debug] Checking for project config at: /stack.yaml
@(Stack/Config.hs:863:9)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.760278: [debug] No project config file found, using defaults.
@(Stack/Config.hs:885:13)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.768047: [debug] Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
@(Stack/Config.hs:464:13)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.769112: [debug] Using resolver: lts-7.18 from implicit global project's config file: /home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
@(Stack/Config.hs:478:32)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.769413: [debug] Trying to decode /home/suzumiya/.stack/build-plan-cache/x86_64-linux/lts-7.18.cache
@(Data/Store/VersionTagged.hs:68:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.783271: [debug] Success decoding /home/suzumiya/.stack/build-plan-cache/x86_64-linux/lts-7.18.cache
@(Data/Store/VersionTagged.hs:72:13)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.807020: [debug] Run process: /sbin/ldconfig -p
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.811417: [debug] Process finished in 4ms: /sbin/ldconfig -p
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.812074: [debug] Run process: /usr/bin/gcc -v
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.814212: [debug] Process finished in 1ms: /usr/bin/gcc -v
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.814849: [debug] PIE enabled
@(Stack/Setup.hs:574:17)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.816948: [debug] Did not find shared library libtinfo.so.5
@(Stack/Setup.hs:564:38)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.817373: [debug] Did not find shared library libtinfo.so.6
@(Stack/Setup.hs:564:38)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.817570: [debug] Found shared library libncursesw.so.6 in 'ldconfig -p' output
@(Stack/Setup.hs:550:29)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.817762: [debug] Found shared library libgmp.so.10 in 'ldconfig -p' output
@(Stack/Setup.hs:550:29)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.818056: [debug] Did not find shared library libgmp.so.3
@(Stack/Setup.hs:564:38)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.818220: [debug] Using ncurses6 GHC build
@(Stack/Setup.hs:600:9)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.830396: [debug] Getting global package database location
@(Stack/GhcPkg.hs:55:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.833333: [debug] Asking GHC for its version
@(Stack/Setup/Installed.hs:103:13)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.833807: [debug] Getting Cabal package version
@(Stack/GhcPkg.hs:189:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.833975: [debug] Run process: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db list --global
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.836559: [debug] Run process: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc --numeric-version
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.839088: [debug] Run process: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db field --simple-output Cabal version
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.908432: [debug] Process finished in 66ms: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db field --simple-output Cabal version
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.943582: [debug] Process finished in 109ms: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db list --global
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.981260: [debug] Process finished in 142ms: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc --numeric-version
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.981640: [debug] Resolving package entries
@(Stack/Setup.hs:252:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.982926: [debug] Starting to execute command inside EnvConfig
@(Stack/Runners.hs:163:18)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.983190: [debug] Parsing the cabal files of the local packages
@(Stack/Build/Source.hs:298:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.983322: [debug] Parsing the targets
@(Stack/Build/Source.hs:235:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.983505: [debug] Finding out which packages are already installed
@(Stack/Build/Installed.hs:68:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:15.983970: [debug] Run process: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --global --no-user-package-db dump --expand-pkgroot
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.045432: [debug] Process finished in 61ms: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --global --no-user-package-db dump --expand-pkgroot
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.069883: [debug] Ignoring package haskeline due to wanting version 0.7.3.0 instead of 0.7.2.3
@(Stack/Build/Installed.hs:191:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.070184: [debug] Ignoring package Cabal due to wanting version 1.24.2.0 instead of 1.24.0.0
@(Stack/Build/Installed.hs:191:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.070511: [debug] Run process: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --user --no-user-package-db --package-db /home/suzumiya/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.137950: [debug] Process finished in 67ms: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --user --no-user-package-db --package-db /home/suzumiya/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.138582: [debug] Run process: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --user --no-user-package-db --package-db /home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.178161: [debug] Process finished in 39ms: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --user --no-user-package-db --package-db /home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.179668: [debug] Trying to decode /home/suzumiya/.stack/indices/Hackage/00-index.cache
@(Data/Store/VersionTagged.hs:68:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.382636: [debug] Success decoding /home/suzumiya/.stack/indices/Hackage/00-index.cache
@(Data/Store/VersionTagged.hs:72:13)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.549706: [debug] Constructing the build plan
@(Stack/Build/ConstructPlan.hs:159:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.552510: [debug] Checking if we are going to build multiple executables with the same name
@(Stack/Build.hs:196:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.552797: [debug] Executing the build plan
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:454:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.553846: [debug] Getting global package database location
@(Stack/GhcPkg.hs:55:5)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.554005: [debug] Run process: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db list --global
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.591687: [debug] Process finished in 37ms: /home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --no-user-package-db list --global
@(System/Process/Read.hs:306:3)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.596523: [debug] Exception ignored when attempting to load /tmp/stack2527/X11-xft-0.3.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/Cabal-1.24.0.0/stack-config-cache: /tmp/stack2527/X11-xft-0.3.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/Cabal-1.24.0.0/stack-config-cache: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
@(Data/Store/VersionTagged.hs:86:9)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.596963: [debug] Exception ignored when attempting to load /tmp/stack2527/X11-xft-0.3.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/Cabal-1.24.0.0/stack-cabal-mod: /tmp/stack2527/X11-xft-0.3.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/Cabal-1.24.0.0/stack-cabal-mod: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
@(Data/Store/VersionTagged.hs:86:9)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.597160: [info] X11-xft-0.3.1: configure
@(Stack/Build/Execute.hs:826:23)
2017-01-30 19:43:16.597834: [debug] Run process: /home/suzumiya/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.0.0_ghc-8.0.1 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/Cabal-1.24.0.0 configure --with-ghc=/home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/suzumiya/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/pkgdb --package-db=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/pkgdb --libdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/lib --bindir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/bin --datadir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/share --libexecdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/etc --docdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/doc/X11-xft-0.3.1 --htmldir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/doc/X11-xft-0.3.1 --haddockdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/doc/X11-xft-0.3.1 --dependency=X11=X11-1.6.1.2-22TNurK7nbm9YWNib5sChe --dependency=base=base-4.9.0.0 --dependency=utf8-string=utf8-string-1.0.1.1-2T8mBCuEDlXDo8zed8Onw4
@(System/Process/Read.hs:340:3)

--  While building package X11-xft-0.3.1 using:
      /home/suzumiya/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.0.0_ghc-8.0.1 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/Cabal-1.24.0.0 configure --with-ghc=/home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/home/suzumiya/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-ncurses6-8.0.1/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/suzumiya/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/pkgdb --package-db=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/pkgdb --libdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/lib --bindir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/bin --datadir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/share --libexecdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/etc --docdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/doc/X11-xft-0.3.1 --htmldir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/doc/X11-xft-0.3.1 --haddockdir=/home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/lts-7.18/8.0.1/doc/X11-xft-0.3.1 --dependency=X11=X11-1.6.1.2-22TNurK7nbm9YWNib5sChe --dependency=base=base-4.9.0.0 --dependency=utf8-string=utf8-string-1.0.1.1-2T8mBCuEDlXDo8zed8Onw4
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/X11-xft-0.3.1.log

    Configuring X11-xft-0.3.1...
    Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.0.0_ghc-8.0.1: Missing dependency on a foreign
    library:
    * Missing C library: Xft
    This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
    provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
    already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
    --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
```

---

I have solved it. It is simply caused by broken old version of freetype2 package using old harfbuzz. It is not about stack build at all.

Comment: Look at the config log. Can you run `pkg-config xft --libs`?

Comment: Added. And log `.stack-work/logs/X11-xft-0.3.1.log`  has been printed.

Comment: Maybe using `--verbose` would be help.

Comment: Cabal and stack logs are known to be a bit terse. Have you looked at /home/suzumiya/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/X11-xft-0.3.1.log? Try to rerun the 'cabal configure' with more verbosity.

Comment: Sorry, I have solved this problem by upgrading freetype2 which was destroyed by new version harfbuzz provided by arch. It seems not related to haskell stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade freetype2. It is simply caused by the broken old version of freetype2 package using old harfbuzz.